# Go json unmarshal not picking up a single attribute value

Tags: json, struct, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal a JSON http response into a Struct I created.

JSON from the API endpoint:

```
[{"Created_Datetime":"2\/16\/2013 2:57:59 AM",
  "Last_Login_Datetime":"11\/27\/2013 11:00:49 PM",
  "Leaves":0,
  "Level":18,
  "Losses":47,
  "MasteryLevel":2,
  "Name":"sergiotapia",
  "Rank_Confidence":0,
  "Rank_Stat":0,
  "TeamId":121147,
  "Team_Name":"sergiosteam",
  "Wins":65,
  "ret_msg":null}]
```

And my struct:

```
type Player struct {
    Created_datetime    string
    Last_login_datetime string
    Leaves              int
    Level               int
    Losses              int
    Mastery_level       int // This is the one that isn't being updated with the value.
    Name                string
    Rank_confidence     int
    Rank_stat           float32
    Team_id             int
    Team_name           string
    Wins                int
    Ret_msg             string
}
```

---

Here's how I'm unmarshaling:

```
var players []Player // Using an array because the API returns a JSON array - always.
json.Unmarshal(httpResponse, &players)
return players[0]
```

Resulting in:

```
// fmt.Println(player)
{2/16/2013 2:57:59 AM 11/27/2013 11:00:49 PM 0 18 47 0 sergiotapia 0 0 0 sergiosteam 65 }
```

Why is the value for MasterLevel not being updated in my struct object?

---

Go Playground here: http://play.golang.org/p/LPNiQDPx2E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mastery_level` is not the same as `MasteryLevel`, just name them the same and it works.

Go Playground here: http://play.golang.org/p/79GfdwS5Wy

Comment: Yup. And you can use struct field tags: `\`json:"MasteryLevel"\`` and then name your field whatever you want.

Comment: While I upvoted the answer, it was also Matt's comment that provided the aha to why I wasn't seeing the expected value (the saved data had a different key than the `json: name` in the struct definition.